# java.io.FileNotFoundException (your file folder) (Access Denied)

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

I have searched everywhere for the answers but I could not find the exact thing. So I revisit my code and verified myself, what is it found was it is not related to the file not found but it is the error in condition checking from content disposition.

Comment: I have searched everywhere for the answers but I could not find the exact thing. So I revisit my code and verified myself, what is it found was it is not related to the file not found but it is the error in condition checking from content disposition.

Comment: On which code above exception is thrown?

Comment: If this is solved in the meantime consider deleting the question (in its current state it is not useful for future visitors). Otherwise please add more details.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"I have searched everywhere for the answers but I could not find the exact thing."* So what were the 3 ***closest*** matches found, and why did those not work? Help us to help you, so we can avoid giving the same advice as has already failed.

Comment: @Henry I wanted to know future visitor where they are making mistake.

Comment: @SonamTshering that would be good, but currently we don't know what the original problem was, nor how it was solved. To make it useful add at least the problematic code and your solution.